# Is there a global database of all products with EAN 13 barcodes which i can integrate with my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, barcode

EAN 13 is an international system. Is there an API or database that contains all items that have these barcodes? Like all food, goods you can buy in a regular convenience store. Is there a global open database for this that i could integrate with my Database and then use it by adding the just the barcode and the all info related to that product will be autopopulated?

Answer (score 5):

Generally we have several different types of EAN code.
We can call them Gtin code.
It could be 8, 12, 13 or 14 digits long.

You could use this database:
https://market.mashape.com/mignify/gtin2product

It's a very user friendly and intelligent API, U can use it to get directly the product information by gtin. Also It could help u to extract the information of a page from E-commerce site.

And the free calls is enough for my necessary in my project.

Hold could help U. keep in contact.